# Is it possible to keep the headers but remove the hyphens of a sql output using sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

**Objective:**

I was able to remove the hyphens when executing a sql query through sqlcmd using

```
|findstr /v /c:"---"
```

The issue however, is I can't combine the above code with my "-o" variable as such:

```
sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -s ";" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT top 5 * FROM table" |findstr /v /c:"---" -o output.csv
```

Error message:

> FINDSTR: Cannot open output.csv

**Note: I need to keep my headers.**

Comment: If you only want the headers don't retrieve the data. You can use the (obsolete) `SET FTMONLY ON;` directive to retrieve just the headers or the [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) stored procedure to get detailed info

Comment: i need my data too

Comment: What are you trying to do then? If you want to export data into a CSV, use the correct command - `bcp`, not `sqlcmd`

Comment: [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) does not feature a `-o` option, but you could use [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to get the result written into a file: `... | findstr /V /C:"---" > "output.csv"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos never used that , what should i do instead?

Comment: @aschipfl that basically does it, ill approve it as a solution if you submit

Comment: BCP is the utility used to import/export bulk data in SQL Server, it's not new. Another option is to use SQL Server Integration Services. [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) is a standalone downloadable program now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) does not feature an option `-o` to create an output file. However, you can use [output redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to write the result into a file, like this:

```cmd
sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -s ";" -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT top 5 * FROM table" | findstr /V /C:"---" > "output.csv"
```

Regard that this will overwrite the file `output.csv` if it already exists without notice. To append to the output file rather than to overwrite it, just replace `>` by `>>`.